# "document.getElementById" return null after a "document.write"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a javascript code to write on my document :

```
nr = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
document.write('<div class="wads-content-' + nr + '" id="flashcontent' + nr + '">'+ flashrequired +'</div>');
var flashcontent = document.getElementById('flashcontent' + nr);
```

In my page, i execute this script twice. The first time everything works, but the second time,  flashcontent is null, but i know it's wrong because I just write the element before the :

```
 document.getElementById
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Using documnet.getElementById should work after a write. There must be an issue with your systax.

Comment: Yes, it works first time but not the second time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use this code :

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = flashrequired;
//Add the flash HTML (embed) in my div
addFlash(div);

var el = '<div class="wads-content-' + nr + '" id="flashcontent' + nr + '">'+ div.innerHTML +'</div>';
document.write(el);
```

So i don't have to find the element in my dom, i create it in javascript and just write it in my document.

Comment: The temporary `div` element object is superfluous here. `var el = '…' + flashrequired + '…';` is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `document.write`, do (good ol' JavaScript)

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "wads-content-" + nr;
div.id = "flashcontent";
div.innerHTML = flashrequired;
```

The jQuery way of doing things:

```
$("<div/>").addClass("wads-content" + nr).attr("id", "flashcontent" + nr);
var flashcontent = $("#flashcontent" + nr);
```

Comment: And how can i add it to my document ? :)

Comment: document.body.appendChild(div); / jQuery - flashcontent.appendTo('body');

Comment: In your jQuery version you would need to append the `div` to the DOM first before being able to select it with `$("#flashcontent")`

Comment: No i want to insert where my script is called.

Comment: How can i do that using document.write and createElement?

Comment: `document.write()` and `document.createElement()` are somewhat mutually exclusive. Use Alex's approach. For `appendChild()` you need a "*static*" element to append to. Martin Honnen suggested inserting before the last `script` element (with [`insertBefore()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727)) if you don't have that, but it may not be reliable. Better have your customers insert an element with ID that you can work with.

Comment: @Sebastien Here's an idea: When the document is being loaded, use `document.write()`to write your content. That would insert it right after the `script` element used to do that. If your function (I presume) is called a the second time, check if an element with that ID already exists. If yes, *do not* call `document.write()` again.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that the second call of `document.write()` occurs after the document has been loaded. The document is overwritten by the call then, as the output stream has been closed. See also [W3C DOM Level 2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75233634).

Comment: Hello, If it was the case, i think my document will be truncate and replace by the string of document.write. Am I wrong?

Comment: That is correct, but note that the document tree differs then. It is not Valid, so all bets are off. If the code is in HTML or served as text/html, you must also escape the ETAGO delimiter (`</`) in the string literal, preferably as `<\/`.

Comment: `text/javascript` is more compatible, but I do not know if that is relevant anymore. Anyhow, so the ETAGO issue does not apply. Still, the generated markup needs to be Valid. You can further try `document.close()` before `document.getElementById(...)`, but I think your best bet is to listen for the `load` event for which it is *specified* that the document has been loaded and the parse tree is complete.

Comment: I can't do that, because i am creating a advertising system and i need to write in my document when the media is called.

Comment: You cannot do *what*? If none of those solutions are possible, use `appendChild()` or `innerHTML` as suggested else-thread, or other DOM methods (see the Spec).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7415/discussion-between-sebastien-and-pointedears)